# How to drop tables with no constraint checking

Tags: sql-server

I need to update the data and schema from dev to staging dbs where I want to DROP/CREATE a group of tables. I need to over-ride the FK constraint checks. Looking at the MS's ALTER TABLE syntax tree - i know it's there but i can't identify the correct syntax.

@Rup: It looks like the hangup is from other tables' FKs. Is there a way to turn all constraint checking off or do i need to produce the list of tables/FKs?

Comment: Do you mean FKs within those tables or from other tables in? Either way I expect you'll have to delete the constaints first, or disable them (if that's possible) at least. You mean ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTAINT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

and a variation on this theme is to disable all the constraints of all the tables delete all the data, and then add all the constraints back again.

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1='alter table ? nocheck constraint all', @whereand='and substring(o.name,1,1) <> ''_'''
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1='delete from ?'
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1='alter table ? check constraint all', @whereand='and substring(o.name,1,1)<> ''_'''
```

The nice thing here is that with all the constraints disabled, you can delete the data in any order

Comment: This sure looks like what i want to do but get - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONSTRAINT'.

Comment: @justSteve --- sorry I just corrected the syntax, shouldn't have included the WITH keyword.

Comment: Much appreciated ... as I'm only looking to effect a subset of all tables in the db - how do I use sp_MSforeachtable against those without effecting the others? oh...and i need to build up the new versions of the tables from scratch so i need to do more than just delete from .... i need to DROP.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the constraints, drop the tables and re-create.  It should also be possible to drop the tables in the correct order and re-create if there are no circular constraints.

[ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)